# Insert XSSFSheet into XSLFSlide as table or image using POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, powerpoint

I would like to insert an excel spreadsheet into a powerpoint slide. I currently have data stored in an XSSFSheet and want to display it on an XSLFSlide which will eventually be exported as a PDF.

The process seems possible considering copying a range of cells from an excel sheet into a slideshow seems to translate well into a ppt table. Converting the sheet into an image and then placing the image onto a slide would also be a viable solution.

If its possible, I would like to use only POI.

Thank you.

Comment: "The process seems possible considering copying a range of cells from an excel sheet into a slideshow seems to translate well into a ppt table.": Yes using the GUIs of Excel and PowerPoint and having the Microsoft code of those GUIs back end. But Apache POI does not have the one nor the other. So only way would be to read the XSSFSheet cell by cell and create a XSLFTable cell by cell from read data. Try this and come back with a more concrete question if you are stuck.